# How do you disable directory listing in AWS CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an S3 bucket. When accessing its root URL via https://s3.amazonaws.com/... it tells me `Access denied`.

This S3 bucket doesn't have any permission rules defined for `Everyone`.

However, accessing the same bucket via our CloudFront `Domain Name` a full `ListBucketResult` is being returned.

**CloudFront is giving a full directory listing, which we want to prevent.**

How can I disable that listing via CloudFront?

I tried invalidating all objects (`*`) in CloudFront, without effect.

Comment: Can you link to the Cloudfront distribution?  I don't recall ever seeing a directory listing via Cloudfront--it's certainly not the default behavior.

Comment: Sure, it's: http://audio.bitesizeirishgaelic.com/ (`C Name` domain) and http://d1c44h11n1ag93.cloudfront.net

Comment: Am also facing the exact same issue. Did you solve it by setting Default Root as mentioned in the best answer ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Did you already get it? If not, you can try setting Default Root object for your cloudfront distribution.

Comment: Thanks that saved me too! My bucket had no permissions whatsoever but still public listing through cloudfront when no default root object set.

Comment: You can also set the Default Root Object to a file that doesn't exist (ex. doesntexist.jpeg) and it will display an error saying "Access Denied".

Answer (score 2):

setting Default Root should work.  Another option is to just put any index.html file at your root.  You could take a blank text file and rename it "index.html", or put some generic HTML message in the file too.  Either way, a call to root of your cloudfront distribution will just default to that file instead of listing your directories / files.